# How's g(x) = sin(x)/x removal discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Because when we draw a graph there have no break point and breakthrough where we can notice that function jumped from his path or removed?? [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGkQ8.jpg]

Comment: A graph is not a proof of anything. Not ever. A graph gives you a hint as to what to expect when you write an actual proof using formulas (limits, in this case).

Comment: In theory, yes, but looking at a graph as a _human_ is not enough. You have to prove that a theoretically ideal observer looking at a graph drawn with a theoretical infinitely thin curve cannot see a break point or anything. That's usually done with more algebra than geometry.

Comment: What is your definition of a removable discontinuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a continuously differentiable function at $x=0$ with $f(0)=0$ and let
\begin{align*}
g(x) :=\frac{f(x)}{x} \text{ for } x\neq 0.
\end{align*}
The following formula is a direct consequence of l'Hopital's rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(0)
\end{align*}

Therefore you can continuously extend $g$ at $0$ by setting $g(0):=f'(0)$.

This is directly applicable to $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 7):

The function $f : \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb R$ defined by the formula $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is *not* discontinuous at $x=0$, because it is not even *defined* there. In most texts you'll find out there, continuity is defined in such a way that functions cannot be continuous or discontinuous at points outside their domain.

However you know from a geometric argument (or Taylor series) that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1, $$
so you may define a *continuous extension* $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ of your function,
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{ \sin x }{x} & x\neq 0, \\ 1 & x=0\end{cases} $$
so the best you can say is that there exists a continuous extension of $f$ that has the real numbers as its domain.

This you can do whenever a function is not defined at a point but has finite limit at that point.

**Addendum.** It is not common practice in real analysis, at least that I know of, but you may define a function to have a *removable singularity* at a point whenever it is not defined at that point, but is defined in its immediate vicinity and has a continuous extension defined at that point. (This is more of a complex-analytic concept, though.)

In this sense you may say thay your function has a removable *singularity* at $x=0$ (instead of a discontinuity).

Comment: Actually, it depends on the definitions you are using. It's not a mistake to say that a function is discontinuous on a point on which it is not defined. After all, a function is continuous if it has a limit on that point which is equal to the value of the function. Hence in any other way the function is discontinuous at the point.

Comment: @Mark See my addendum.

Comment: @Mark Discontinuity and continuity both require, in their conventionally agreed upon definition (the aptly called "$\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition"), that a function actually has a defined value at the point of continuity / discontinuity. If you want to use another definition (say, if you're a high-school teacher and don't want to scare all the kids away), then you do you, but it is, as said, not convention.

Comment: Arthur, not at all. It all depends on how you decide to define it. How would you call the problem that $\frac{sinx}{x}$ has at the point $x=0$?

Comment: @Mark I would call it a removable singularity.

Comment: That's fine. But for me it's still a point at which the function is not continuous.

Comment: @Mark I agree that it isn't continuous. I just also think it isn't discontinuous. The function at that point just... isn't.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter after all. There are no right or wrong definitions.

Comment: @Mark I can’t do much more than to direct you to any good book on real analysis, complex analysis, general topology, or any field of math where some notion of continuity is needed. The conventional way to do things, besides the fact that it’s the one that most people agree on, is also the least confusing, since it clearly distinguishes between points where the function is defined and points where it isn’t.

Comment: giobrach, again, it doesn't matter. I don't remember a situation in which the question whether it is called discontinuity or not effected the solution of a problem on that subject. It's just about how we call it. I also call it a removable singularity by the way.

Comment: If you really want to do things properly you shouldn't start with "The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$..." because $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not a function.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That’s true! I got carried away by my complex-analytic spirit. :)

Comment: Thanks ! It helped a lot. giobrach

Comment: @MIKEYSINGH glad to have helped!